# Are there any books, websites, etc. that have many practice problems for Skew-T diagrams and the atmospheric sciences in general?

Tags: meteorology, homework, reference-request, radiosounding

I am asking because my Intro to Atmospheric Science class (lectures, labs, and the book) has not provided any practice examples of Skew-T diagrams, Coriolis force calculations, LCL (liquid condensation level) calculations, and 'What is wrong with this diagram?'-type problems.

I prefer that online, free resources be listed first.  If there are resources such as workbooks or lab manuals or subscription based services that are available, please list those afterwards.

Comment: Check the UCAR website for this METED material.

Comment: @gan Can you please link the relevant UCAR website?